# Calculation Within mySQL With a Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a mySQL query to calculate some values.

essentially I want to select a single column from a table, I want to count how many of each values there are and then give that to the user.

So:

```
SELECT numeric_values FROM answerTable
IF numeric_values == '1.00' THEN new_variable1 ++
IF numeric_values == '2.00' THEN new_variable2 ++
IF numeric_values == '3.00' THEN new_variable3 ++
IF numeric_values == '4.00' THEN new_variable4 ++
RETURN new_variable1 ++
RETURN new_variable2 ++
RETURN THEN new_variable3 ++
RETURN THEN new_variable4 ++
;
```

I really havent got a clue where to start looking or if these types of operators are even available in mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT numeric_values,COUNT(numeric_values)as name FROM answerTable
GROUP BY numeric_values
```